# mongodb meaning of dot and a dollar sign

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am debugging a code which used flask_pymongo

and I see this code

```
   dabb = mongo.db.tbl.find({
            "transactions": {'$elemMatch': {"from":{'$elemMatch':{"from":str(to)}},"to":{'$elemMatch':{"to":str(frm)}}}}
        },{"transactions.$": 1 })
```

I don't understand what does that {"transactions.$": 1 } do.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

Answer (score 7):

### The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

**It limits the contents of an array to return either:**

1. The first element that matches the query condition on the array.
2. The first element if no query condition is specified for the array (Starting in MongoDB 4.4).

```
    dabb = mongo.db.tbl.find({
            "transactions": {
                 '$elemMatch': {
                          "from":{
                             '$elemMatch':{ "from":str(to) }
                                 },
                          "to": {
                             '$elemMatch':{"to":str(frm)}
                                 }
                              }
                           }          // Only apply for first element then meet query condition within an array
                         },          //  when a element meet the query condition 
          {"transactions.$": 1 })   //   it will only return that element from array
```

After getting the first  element in transition array that meet the query condition it will return that element.
See documentation with a lot of example

- [$ (projection)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

In your case this link is more suitable:

- [$ (update)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)